# Icon is not aligned to right

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap accordion and I want to have a arrow right at the right of the link, but with text-right to align the text at right is not working. Do you know why? Also do you know how to toggle the awesome font from `<i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>` to `<i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i>` when the user clicks in the link?

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/921bdzsu/

HTML:

```
<div class="container py-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
            <h5 class="mb-0">
              <a class="text-custom-blue-dark" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                Title
              </a>
              <span class="ml-auto text-right"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></span>
            </h5>
          </div>

          <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
            <div class="card-body">
              <p class="faq-answer">
                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: put <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i> inside the anchor tag <a></a>. No need for separate span

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`span` elements by default are `inline`. So they occupy the exact width of the content. You could use a `div` instead but it would fall in the next line.

Your best options would be is to use positioning or float the element. But the cleanest I feel is using `flex`

```
.mb-0 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/921bdzsu/18/

Comment: OP question is confusing if this is not what they want then it's just text-align:right on the .card-header

Comment: Thanks, do you know why is necessary to click in the text to show the content? Why dont works if the click is in another area of the .card-header div?

Comment: That is because you are using the accordion component. By default it has the `collapse` class associated to the panel

Comment: Thanks, but like that is necessary to click in the arrow to toggle, do you know how to toggle even if the user click in other area of the h5?

Comment: @user10676579 that's because what triggers the collapse is the `a` tag, in order to make the full header clickable you have to make the `a` tag to fill its full width, and for that you need to make the `a` tag a block or `inline-block` since it's an `inline` element by default

Comment: Thanks, with the data-toggle and data-target attributes in the h5 instead of the a it works, when the user clicks in any area of the card-header it shows, however the icon font only toggle if the user clicks in the arrow but if the user clicks in any other area of the card-header the icon font dont toggle.